# Detach a paid app from play store

Tags: google-play-store, systemless-root

I have the APK of the last good version of ROM Toolbox Pro, which had the app manager, and so far I've had to disable auto update to prevent it from being replaced by the newer version.

This is an app I purchased back in the day when it didn't have its features truncated, so deleting it from my play store library isn't an option. I've tried the Magisk detach module, but that messed up play store and I had to reset my phone.

How does one manually delink  the app? The phone is obviously rooted, using Magisk systemless root.

Comment: AFAIK not possible. Even if you unlink it (Titanium Backup has an option for that), Playstore App will re-link it within 24h.

Comment: The Magisk module works but inconsistently, at one time it ended up permanently crashing play store. So I'm looking for the general principle behind detaching apps.

Comment: By delink the app, do you mean stop it from updating.

Comment: Yes, and beyond simply disabling the 'enable auto update' option on its page, because it still ignores the setting and gets updated anyway once in a while. I don't want to see it in the list of pending updates at all.

Comment: Only option is to rebuild the application package with a different package name or to change the version to a newer one than is available online...  I use APK Editor to do repackaging and version changes... No matter what you do otherwise, Google Play will recognise the Application by the package name and then check the version in the application manifest to calculate if you need an update...

Comment: Doesn't it need a signing certificate if you repackage it?